# background image disappears after using button in postbacktrigger of update panel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Background image disappears after using button in postbacktrigger of update panel in asp.net.I have designed registraion form and have placed all controls in update panel.After clicking on submit button,data gets submitted ,the page refreshes and background image dissappears.The values are getting properly inserted in database.
            PFB the HTML code for Registration.aspx:-

```
        <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="Register" %>
        <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
        <%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/FacebookUserControl.ascx" TagName="facebookheader" TagPrefix="Uc1"%>

        <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
            <style type="text/css">
                .auto-style1 {
                    width: 100%;
                }
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function HideCtrl(ctrl, timer) {
                    var ctry_array = ctrl.split(","); 
                    var num = 0, arr_length = ctry_array.length; 
                    while (num < arr_length) {
                        if (document.getElementById(ctry_array[num])) {
                            setTimeout('document.getElementById("' + ctry_array[num] + '").style.display = "none";', timer);
                        } 
                        num += 1;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            </script>
             <script>
                 $(function () {
                     //  Initialize Backgound Stretcher
                     $('BODY').bgStretcher({
                         images: ['images/slide-1.jpg'],
                         imageWidth: 1600,
                         imageHeight: 964,
                         resizeProportionally: true

                     });
                 });
            </script>

        </asp:Content>
        <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

            <form id="form1" runat="server">

                <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager> 

            <section id="content">
            <div class="main-block">
                <div class="container_12">
                    <div class="wrapper">

                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg1" HeaderText="Fields marked with (*) are required" 
                                        ForeColor="Red" CssClass="error" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div id="divErrorMess" runat="server" visible="false" class="mess">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="divBallon" runat="server" visible="false" class="mess">
                                        <div>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage2" runat="server" Visible="False" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                        <table style="width:358px; border:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;Full Name</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtFullName" runat="server" placeholder="Enter your Full Name" ValidationGroup="vg1" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;<span style="color:red">*</span>&nbsp;
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFullName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtFullName" Display="None" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" 
                                ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;Date Of Birth</td>
                    </tr>                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;<%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateOfBirth" runat="server" placeholder="Enter your Date Of Birth" ValidationGroup="vg1" Width="250px" ClientIDMode="Static">
                                  </asp:TextBox>--%><%--                    &nbsp;<span style="color:red">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Format="MM-dd-yyyy" 
                                TargetControlID="txtDateOfBirth"></asp:CalendarExtender>--%><%-- <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDob" runat="server" ErrorMessage="" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtDateOfBirth" Display="None" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" 
                                ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonth" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMonth_SelectedIndexChanged" placeholder="Month" AutoPostBack="true">
                              </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;<span style="color:red">*</span>&nbsp;
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvMonth" 
                                  runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="ddlMonth" ForeColor="Red" 
                                  SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>&nbsp;
                              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                              </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;<span style="color:red">*</span>&nbsp;
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDate" 
                                  runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="ddlDate" ForeColor="Red" 
                                  SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>&nbsp;
                              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlYear_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">

                              </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;<span style="color:red">*</span>&nbsp;
                              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvYear" runat="server" 
                                  ErrorMessage="*" 
                                  ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="vg1" 
                                  ControlToValidate="ddlYear"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;Phone Number</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtPhoneNumber" runat="server" placeholder="Enter your Phone Number" ValidationGroup="vg1" Width="250px">
                                  </asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;<span style="color:red">*</span>&nbsp;
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPhone" runat="server" ErrorMessage="" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtPhoneNumber" Display="None" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" 
                                ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>&nbsp;
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revPhone" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter only 10 digit number" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtPhoneNumber" Display="None" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" 
                                ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{10}" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;Email Address</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" placeholder="Enter your Email address" ValidationGroup="vg1" Width="250px">
                                  </asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;<span style="color:red">*</span>&nbsp;
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtEmail" Display="None" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" 
                                ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>&nbsp;
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email!" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtEmail" Display="None" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" 
                                ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ValidationGroup="vg1">
                            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;Submit 2 Photos</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"  Width="250px" />
                            &nbsp;<span style="color:red">*</span>&nbsp;
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPhoto1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="" 
                                ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" Display="None" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" 
                                ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" Width="250px"/>
                            &nbsp;<span style="color:red">*</span>&nbsp;
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPhoto2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="" 
                                ControlToValidate="FileUpload2" Display="None" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" 
                                ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;Terms & Conditions</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAgree" runat="server" />&nbsp;I agree to Terms and Conditions</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/submit.png" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" ValidationGroup="vg1" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnReset" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/reset.png" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btnReset_Click" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlMonth" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlDate" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlYear" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit"                        />                        
                            </Triggers>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <Uc1:facebookheader ID="fbtag" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>                     



            </section> 
        <%--    </div> --%>     
            </form>
        </asp:Content>
```

**PFB code for Registration.aspx.cs:**

The below code contains data for registration.aspx. In the below i have used dropdownlist to enter date as input and necessary validations are performed for date.I have used arraylist to add months and used for loop to add years.Also i have used CheckLeapYear fn to check leap year.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net.Mail;
    using System.Collections;

    public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        int year;
        string month;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl divmain = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("divmain");
            //divmain.Attributes.Add("class", "extra-block");        
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                this.Page.Title = "Register Us With Now to kick start your Career in MatureModelling";
                this.Page.MetaDescription = 
                   "MatureModelling connects new faces and models with scouts, international model photo " 
                   + "shoot and photographers. Casting Directors are now Looking" 
                   + " For real Models To Front Their Campaigns.";
                this.Page.MetaKeywords = 
                   "international photographers, expert model advice";

                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl aRegister = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("Register");
                aRegister.Attributes.Add("class", "current");

                Response.Cache.SetNoStore();


                DateTime tnow = DateTime.Now;

                ArrayList ayear = new ArrayList();
                int i;
                for (i = 1970; i <= DateTime.Now.Year; i++)
                {
                    ayear.Add(i);
                }

                ArrayList amonth = new ArrayList();
                amonth.Add("Jan");
                amonth.Add("Feb");
                amonth.Add("Mar");
                amonth.Add("Apr");
                amonth.Add("May");
                amonth.Add("Jun");
                amonth.Add("Jul");
                amonth.Add("Aug");
                amonth.Add("Sep");
                amonth.Add("Oct");
                amonth.Add("Nov");
                amonth.Add("Dec");            

                ddlYear.DataSource = ayear;
                ddlYear.DataBind();

                ddlMonth.DataSource = amonth;
                ddlMonth.DataBind();

                ddlYear.SelectedValue = tnow.Year.ToString();
                ddlMonth.SelectedValue = tnow.Month.ToString();

                year = Int32.Parse(ddlYear.SelectedValue);
                month = Convert.ToString(ddlMonth.SelectedValue);

                BindDays(year, month);
                ddlDate.SelectedValue = tnow.Day.ToString();
            }
        }

        #region Button Event
        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "";
            string strScript = string.Empty;
            string strCtrl = divErrorMess.ClientID;
            strScript = "HideCtrl('" + strCtrl + "', '3000')";
            try
            {
                if (chkAgree.Checked)
                {
                    Registration objRegistration = new Registration();

                    objRegistration.FirstName = txtFullName.Text.Trim().ToString();
                    //objRegistration.BirthDate = txtDateOfBirth.Text.Trim().ToString();
                    objRegistration.BirthDate = ddlYear.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() 
                                                + "-" + ddlMonth.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() 
                                                + "-" + ddlDate.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
                    objRegistration.EmailId = txtEmail.Text.Trim().ToString();
                    objRegistration.PhoneNo = txtPhoneNumber.Text.Trim().ToString();

                    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                    {

                        objRegistration.Photo1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
                    }
                    string pathBig = Server.MapPath("~\\ModelPhotos\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString());
                    ViewState["pathBig"] = pathBig;
                    if (File.Exists(pathBig))
                    {
                        //File.Delete(pathBig);
                        FileUpload1.SaveAs(pathBig);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FileUpload1.SaveAs(pathBig);
                    }

                    if (FileUpload2.HasFile)
                    {
                        objRegistration.Photo2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + FileUpload2.FileName.ToString();
                    }
                    string pathBig1 = Server.MapPath("~\\ModelPhotos\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy")+FileUpload2.FileName.ToString());
                    ViewState["pathBig1"] = pathBig1;
                    if (File.Exists(pathBig1))
                    {
                        //File.Delete(pathBig1);
                        FileUpload2.SaveAs(pathBig1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FileUpload2.SaveAs(pathBig1);
                    }

                    if (chkAgree.Checked)
                    {
                        objRegistration.IsAgree = "true";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        objRegistration.IsAgree = "false";
                    }

                    RegistrationOperation objRegisterOperation = new RegistrationOperation();
                    int k = Convert.ToInt32(objRegisterOperation.InsertRegisterUser(objRegistration));

                    if (k==0)
                    {
                        divErrorMess.Visible = false;
                        divBallon.Visible = true;
                        lblMessage2.Visible = true;
                        lblMessage2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        lblMessage2.Text = "User Created Successfully!";
                        lblMessage.Text = string.Empty;
                        Session["result"] = "insert";
                       // sendmail();
                       // sendmailtoadmin();
                        fnClearControls();
                        divBallon.Visible = true;
                        strScript="HideCtrl('"+divBallon.ClientID+"','3000')";
                    }
                    else if (k==1)
                    {
                        divErrorMess.Visible = true;
                        lblMessage.Visible = true;
                        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        lblMessage.Text = "Sorry,Please try again!";
                        divBallon.Visible = false;
                    }
                    else if (k==2)
                    {
                        divErrorMess.Visible = true;
                        lblMessage.Visible = true;
                        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
                        lblMessage.Text = "Email Id already exists!";
                        divBallon.Visible = false;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    divErrorMess.Visible = true;
                    lblMessage.Visible = true;
                    lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
                    lblMessage.Text = "Please accept terms & conditions";
                    divBallon.Visible = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
           Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), strScript, true);
        }


        protected void btnReset_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            fnClearControls();
            divBallon.Visible = false;
            divErrorMess.Visible = false;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Method

        private void fnClearControls()
        {
            txtFullName.Text = " ";
            //txtLastName.Text = "";
            txtPhoneNumber.Text = "";
            // txtParentsPhoneNumber.Text = "";
            txtEmail.Text = "";
            chkAgree.Checked = false;
            //txtDateOfBirth.Text = "";
            ddlDate.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ddlMonth.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ddlYear.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Year);

        }  


        public void FillDays()
        {
            ddlDate.Items.Clear();
            //getting numbner of days in selected month & year
            int noofdays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(ddlYear.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue));

            //Fill days
            for (int i = 0; i <= noofdays; i++)
            {
                ddlDate.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }
            ddlDate.Items.FindByValue(System.DateTime.Now.Day.ToString()).Selected = true;
        }

        private bool CheckLeapYear(int year)
        {
            if ((year%4==0)&&(year%100!=0)||(year%400==0))        
                return true;
                else return false;

        }

        private void BindDays(int year, string month)
        {
            int i;
            ArrayList aday = new ArrayList();
            switch (month)
            {
                case "Jan":
                case "Mar":
                case "May":
                case "Jul":
                case "Aug":
                case "Oct":
                case "Dec":
                    for (i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
                    {
                        aday.Add(i);
                    }
                    break;
                case "Feb":

                    if (CheckLeapYear(year))
                    {
                        for (i = 1; i <= 29; i++)
                            aday.Add(i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (i = 1; i <= 28; i++)
                            aday.Add(i);
                    }
                    break;
                case "Apr":
                case "Jun":
                case "Sep":
                case "Nov":
                    for (i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
                        aday.Add(i);
                    break;
            }

            ddlDate.DataSource = aday;
            ddlDate.DataBind();
        }

        #endregion

    Following are dropdownlist events adn BindDays fn is used.
        #region DDL events

        protected void ddlYear_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            year = Int32.Parse(ddlYear.SelectedValue);
            month = Convert.ToString(ddlMonth.SelectedValue);
            BindDays(year, month);
        }
Following are dropdownlist events adn BindDays fn is used.
        protected void ddlMonth_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            year = Int32.Parse(ddlYear.SelectedValue);
            month = Convert.ToString(ddlMonth.SelectedValue);
            BindDays(year, month);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you probably just need to call that JavaScript function that initializes your "Background Stretcher" on each UpdatePanel update (rather than just when the DOM loads).  Changing that function to this should do the trick:

```
function pageLoad() { 
    $('BODY').bgStretcher({
        images: ['images/slide-1.jpg'],
        imageWidth: 1600,
        imageHeight: 964,
        resizeProportionally: true
    });
}
```

Notice that I used `function pageLoad() {` (should be called on each postback, including AJAX partial postbacks) rather than `$(function () {` (only called once, when the DOM loads).